# Powershell script to replace pattern YY to YYYY

Tags: powershell, design-patterns, replace, foreach, get-childitem

I am not the Powershell pro so I need some help.

What I have now is for example:

**somelongname_08-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf**

and I want a rename to

**somelongname_2008-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf**

In short changing two digit year format to four digit year format within the name of multiple files.

At the moment I use the following script to rename all files in a specific folder:

`get-childitem *.* | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_08-", "_2008-") }`

I do not want to achieve it by copying the above formula to:
...
`get-childitem *.* | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_08-", "_2008-") }`
`get-childitem *.* | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_09-", "_2009-") }`
`get-childitem *.* | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_10-", "_2010-") }`
...

So is there a more elegant and fast way, because the years may vary from +- 1925-2023

The basic search and replace pattern is always the same and its's unique in each filename and begins with `_` contains two numbers for the year and ends with `-`.

So I have two cases
-) years from 25 to 99 need at the beginning an "19"
-) years from 00 to 23 need at the beginning an "20"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) to handle the logic if `20` or `19` should be prepended to the string, for example:

```
$re = [regex] '(?<=_)\d{2}(?=-)'

'somelongname_08-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf',
'somelongname_25-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf',
'somelongname_24-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf' | ForEach-Object {
    $re.Replace($_, {
        switch($args[0].Value) {
            { $_ -ge 25 -and $_ -le 99 } {
                return '19' + $_
            }
            { $_ -ge 0 -and $_ -le 23 } {
                return '20' + $_
            }
            # leave it as-is if it didn't match the above conditions
            Default { $_ }
        }
    })
}
```

If this is what you were looking for, you can include it to your `Rename-Item`:

```
$re = [regex] '(?<=_)\d{2}(?=-)'

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $re.Replace($_.Name, {
        switch($args[0].Value) {
            { $_ -ge 25 -and $_ -le 99 } {
                return '19' + $_
            }
            { $_ -ge 0 -and $_ -le 23 } {
                return '20' + $_
            }
            Default { $_ }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: First thanks for your reply. I am not able to completely understand your solution but as I mentioned in the other comment, I forgot an important detail to add:

The filenames often contain additional underscores like 
`long_file_name_08-01-01_second_part_of_long_filename.pdf` unique part of each filename is `_YY-` which should be `_YYYY-` (or the complete date between the underscores yy-mm-dd)

Comment: @idontkn0w123 is the code not working? `(?<=_)\d{2}` will look for an underscore followed by 2 digits specifically

Comment: I did not try yet, just arrived home. But how can I, to be completely sure, change the pattern to underscore followed by 2 digits and an "-" that would be 100% sure that it does not select any wrong numbers

Comment: if the specific pattern is `_` followed by 2 numeric digits followed by `-` I could refine the regex a bit more, i.e.: `(?<=_)\d{2}(?=-)` other than that I dont see how much can be improved

Comment: Ok thats great. Now one last question, how can I use your script? Before I just selected the needed path in powershell with `cd "C:/ ......... " ` and then copied my code `get-childitem *.* | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_08-", "_2008-") }` and just changed the numbers for the year. But yours has lots of lines. How to use it best? Sorry I'm really not that experienced with powershell commands and usage

Comment: @idontkn0w123 do a copy of some of these files and test the code against that copy of the files so you're sure the code is doing what you want. aside from that, the code as-is will handle all cases for you you don't need to run a copy of the code for each year or something like that. Just cd to the path where the `pdf` files are and run the code that's it

Comment: It works very good, ofc I first tried with some renamed emty files. I do not have all files in 1 folder but lots of folders with lots of subfolders etc. Did already serveral folders with some 100 files at total and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the century that is chosen will depend on the half-century year, so if the two-digit year is 50, this will be regarded as 1950 and anything below 50 will become 20xx

You can use .Net for this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*_*_*.pdf' -File) | ForEach-Object { 
    # split the file BaseName in three parts
    $prefix, $date, $postfix = $_.BaseName -split '_', 3
    # let .Net parse out the date. 
    # Up to and including year 49, this century is used, year 50 and above will become the 1900's
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($date,'yy-MM-dd', $null)
    $newName = '{0}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd}_{2}{3}' -f $prefix, $date, $postfix, $_.Extension
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName
}
```

Result:

```
somelongname_08-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf --> somelongname_2008-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf
somelongname_25-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf --> somelongname_2025-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf
somelongname_49-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf --> somelongname_2049-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf
somelongname_50-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf --> somelongname_1950-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf
```

---

If however you have good reason to deviate from this, you can do:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*_*_*.pdf' -File) | ForEach-Object { 
    # split the file BaseName in three parts
    $prefix, $date, $postfix = $_.BaseName -split '_', 3
    $century = if ([int]$date.Substring(0,2) -ge 25) { 19 } else { 20 }
    $newName = '{0}_{1}{2}_{3}{4}' -f $prefix, $century, $date, $postfix, $_.Extension
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName
}
```

Result now:

```
somelongname_08-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf --> somelongname_2008-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf
somelongname_25-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf --> somelongname_1925-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf
somelongname_49-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf --> somelongname_1949-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf
somelongname_50-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf --> somelongname_1950-01-01_someotherlongname.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I made a mistake, I did not give you all the informations. The filenames often contain additional underscores like
`long_file_name_08-01-01_second_part_of_long_filename.pdf`
unique part of each filename is `_YY-` which should be `_YYYY-`

Comment: @idontkn0w123 Ah, ok. It's getting late in my part of the world, so I'm on mobile now. I can give you code to handle that, but not until tomorrow